# Process.waitFor() not "waiting" for current thread to finish

Tags: java, process, wait

I have an excel sheet where it has a list of jar files to be executed. To kick start the testing, I will run a code to read from the said excel sheet and execute the jar files in the excel sheet. The code to run those jar files is as follow :

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd /k java -jar " + start.jar_filepath + " " + start.tc_name + " " + start.test_data + " " + start.test_result + " " + start.test_cycle);
```

This will actually run all the jar files concurrently.

I actually wanted  one jar to be executed at one time, and the next jar to be executed AFTER the current jar has finish execution.

I added the following.

```
p.waitFor();
```

However, it still behaves the same, that is, it is executed simultaneously.

Am I using the waitFor() wrongly ? Advice is appreciated.

Update:
The following is the code that iterates the excel sheet

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, Throwable {
        final DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
        final FileInputStream StartInput = new FileInputStream("c:\\TA\\TestConfig_MA.xlsx");
        final XSSFWorkbook StartInputWB = new XSSFWorkbook(StartInput);
        final XSSFSheet sheet = StartInputWB.getSheet("Config");
        System.out.println("Amount of Row in test config : "+ sheet.getLastRowNum());
        start.count = 1;
        //while (start.count <= sheet.getLastRowNum()) {
        for(start.count = 1; start.count <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); start.count++){  
            System.out.println("Total test case = " + sheet.getLastRowNum());
            System.out.println(start.count);
            final XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(start.count);
            start.testability = row.getCell(0).toString();            
            start.jar_filepath = row.getCell(1).toString();
            start.tc_name = row.getCell(2).toString();
            start.test_data = row.getCell(3).toString();
            start.test_result = row.getCell(4).toString();
            start.test_cycle = df.formatCellValue(row.getCell(5));
            System.out.println("test cycle from start.jar = " + start.test_cycle);
            System.out.println("Test Case Name : " + start.tc_name);
            if (start.testability.equals("Y") || start.testability.equals("y)")) {
                System.out.println("Test Case Name : " + start.tc_name);
                System.out.println("Round : " + start.count);
                final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd /k java -jar " + start.jar_filepath + " " + start.tc_name + " " + start.test_data + " " + start.test_result + " " + start.test_cycle);
                p.waitFor();
                System.out.println("wait for = " +p.waitFor());
            else {
                System.out.println("Its a no");
            }
           // ++start.count;
        }//for
        System.out.println("test is done");
    }
   
    }
```

Comment: can you please provide a [mre] where you show how you are looping over the excel rows, how you're waiting and how you handle exceptions. Currently we can't tell you if you did something wrong, because we don't have enough information

Comment: @Lino Gladly. Let me just add into the main question

Answer (score 1):

why you need `"cmd /c start cmd /k ..."`?
You run `cmd` which runs `start` which runs `cmd` which runs `java`

In particular, `start` opens a new window and returns immediately. Therefore `p.waitFor();` will wait for `start` to complete, but not the new window opened by it.

You may want to narrow it to simple

`...exec("java -jar " + ...)`

or at least

`...exec("cmd /c java -jar " + ...)`

Comment: can you also advise me on how to assign ```` p.waitFor() ```` to the opened window ?

Comment: I have tried both your recommendation, and I am not able to run the jar files. Do advice me on how to share with you the log file I got from appium. Also, I need to have the cmd window opened as well.